# Problems compiling Hadoop

Tags: compilation, hadoop

That's the problem: I have done a simply Hadoop program to "clean" a graph saved in a text file that I will use later (with Hadoop), but I can't compile it!

The compiler can't find Hadoop classes (IntWritable, Text ecc...), and each time I get a "cannot find symbol" error.

I've tried with:

```
javac -classpath path/to/hadoop/root/hadoop-core-{version}.jar filename.java
```

I'm running with ubuntu 11.04, and the Hadoop version is 1.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that hadoop-core-{version}.jar depends on some other jars. You can find all the dependencies on the Maven repository web site :

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/1.0.3

You should use Maven or add all the dependencies to your project to be able to build it.